# Get JavaScript-Object from String

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, object

When having:

```
var text ='{"parameter":"value"}';
```

I can use JSON.parse(text); to create a JavaScript Object.

**Problem:**
I have `'{ parameter: "value" }'` coming from an axios.default.post request. JSON.parse throws an error for that.

So, how can I create an object from that?

***EDIT*****
The response comes from an axios request. I debugged it through transformResponse now and in that stage, the data is still{"parameter":"value"}. So, Axios creates my problem by - whyever - removing the "; have to figure out, why.

Thanks for your answers, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Where do you have that string from? Sounds to me like there is an issue there rather than how to convert it to an object.

Comment: Can you tell what is the error?

Comment: This is not valid JSON. So JSON.parse won't help. But what's up? You already seem to have an object. Just use it.

Comment: The response comes from an axios request. I debugged it through transformResponse now and in that stage, the data is still{"parameter":"value"}. So, Axios creates my problem by - whyever - removing the "; have to figure out, why. 

Thanks for your answers, I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should let api response the correct json valid data. I don't recommand to handle this invalid json string by frontend.

---

**Update:**

According to your issue have you try this config?

```
// `transformResponse` allows changes to the response data to be made before
// it is passed to then/catch
transformResponse: [function (data) {
  // Do whatever you want to transform the data
      return data;
}],
```

Hope this help

Comment: Well, it's not my API ;) But see answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Axios, When receiving JSON from the server, Axios seems to format it to a different format, even though it stays a string when doing "typeof".

My solution was to add responseType="text" to the config for the request.
This way, I receive a text, that I can parse with JSON.parse.

However, this is somehow not perfect, as Axios provides JSON formating, so, if anyone has an answer to "How can I use the Axios formated Result", I'ld be happy to know about it.

Answer (score -1):

`'{ parameter: "value"}'` is not JSON as you've probably figured out as the key isn't wrapped in quotes. There is a trick that you can use to turn a javascript object string back into an object.

As @ASDFGerte noted this is not a safe method if you are not sure of your string's source.

```js
function parse(str) {
  return Function('"use strict";return (' + str + ')')();
}

const obj = parse('{ parameter: "value"}');

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I advise against using `eval` or the `Function` constructor here, especially if it is not absolutely certain the string is from a safe source.

Comment: This is very true.